# Is valid add npa 0 in bundle extras for personalized ads in consent SDK admob?

Tags: android, admob

I hope you are well.

Is valid adding npa 0 in the bundle to request personalized ads or we need to make another object for this?

According to the documentation what it says here [Forward consent to the Google Mobile Ads SDK](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent#forward_consent_to_the_google_mobile_ads_sdk)

This is for request non-personalized ads

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("npa", "1");
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
        .build();
```

According to the documentation it says:

> If non-personalized ads are requested, the ad request URL currently
>   includes **&npa=1**. However, note that this is an internal implementation
>   detail of the Google Mobile Ads SDK and is subject to change.

If i want to request personalized ads i can put 0?

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();extras.putString("npa", "0");
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to request personalized ads, there is no need to use `addNetworkExtrasBundle()`.

Simply use,

```
AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
if (/*Request non-personalized ads*/) {
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("npa", "1");
    builder.addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras);
}
AdRequest request = builder.build();
```